# how convert mariadb ddl with AES_ENCRYPT to jooq?

Tags: java, mysql, mariadb, jooq

```
rwDsl.insertInto(table)
                .columns(
                        table.TITLE,
                        table.DESCRIPTION
                        )
                .values(
                        aesEncrypt(
                                x.getTitle(), 
                                sha1(concat("", Long.toString(created)).toString())
                        ),
                        aesEncrypt(x.getDescription(), concat("", Long.toString(created)).toString()).toString().getBytes())
```

not working...

i want this ddl convert jooq

```
insert into table(title, description) 
values (AES_ENCRYPT("title_test", "11111"),AES_ENCRYPT("description_test", "11111"))
```

Answer (score 0):

When jOOQ doesn't support some vendor specific function, always use [plain SQL templating](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/plain-sql-templating/):

```java
public static Field<String> aesEncrypt(
    Field<String> string, 
    Field<String> keyString
) {
    return DSL.field("aes_encrypt({0}, {1})", 
        string.getDataType(), 
        string, 
        keyString
    );
}
```